# Running trigger that calls stored procedure on another database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers, cross-database

We would like to run a trigger on one database (A) that calls a stored procedure on another database (B).

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_A ON TableA
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    EXEC DatabaseB.dbo.stp_B
END
```

We would like to do this as LoginA with UserA on DatabaseA. We also have LoginB with UserB on DatabaseB.

How can we accomplish this?

Currently we get this error message

```
The server principal "..." is not able to access the 
database "DatabaseB" under the current security context.
```

---

We have tried `WITH EXECUTE AS 'UserB'`, without luck.

Comment: Please tag this with the database product you're using.

Comment: Any reason you cannot grant LoginA rights on DatabaseB - limited to that one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question. You nerd-sniped me. I tested a bunch of different scenarios.

These failed:

1. Trigger on tableA references stored procedure in DatabaseB. LoginA does not exist as a user in DatabaseB.
2. Trigger on tableA references stored procedure in DatabaseA that inserts into DatabaseB.dbo.TableB. LoginA does not exist in DatabaseB.
3. Created LoginA as a user on DatabaseB, but didn't give it any rights. Repeated test1 and test2. Both failed.
4. Created LoginB as a user on DatabaseA. Made sure LoginB could insert into DatabaseB.dbo.TableB. Logged into DatabaseA as LoginA, ran EXECUTE AS User = 'LoginB'. Tried to insert into DatabaseA.dbo.TableA.

The only way I could get the trigger to work was to create a user in DatabaseB for LoginA and grant permissions to execute the DatabaseB stored procedure.